# How can we remove box shadow from left or right in this design?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-transitions, border, box-shadow

Here is my example image: [image]

```
Codepan : [https://codepen.io/vijayhardaha/details/GRgLgZR][2]
```

if anyone knows that how can we disappear the box-shadow from the left or right(Check Image)? I don't want to be offset to move left or right. That will not fit into my design.

If anyone has any idea or trick please suggest to me. It's an Input group, and on the focus, I am applying a box-shadow on input and input append item.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a code to share? It will be easier to solve this if we can see code structure.. From the image, it looks like you could remove the shadow from search icon button.

Comment: Which library are you use ? Please put your code here.

Comment: [Codepan](https://codepen.io/vijayhardaha/pen/GRgLgZR)

I am using an Input Group. You can see the example.

Answer (score 0):

I have created two diffrent boxes in html and applied box-shadow css to both.

this removes box-shadow from the right side of box box-shadow: -10px 15px 8px 5px #888888; (search-bar box)

this removes box-shadow from the left side of box box-shadow: 10px 15px 8px 5px #888888; (search icon box)

Comment: Changing the offset is not going to work. Because I will break the design and look.
And if even I solve this problem with moving offset. and try to hide an extra `4px offset`. Problem is I am using `4px border-radius` that will cause be also hidden when I will try to hide extra 4px from the input(left) and search icon (right)

Comment: [link](https://codepen.io/vijayhardaha/details/GRgLgZR) Here is codepan.